# Random Bytes in array when encoding to different charachter set Java

Tags: java, character-encoding

I am trying to text to bytes however when I call:

```
Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-16");  
ByteBuffer bytes = charset.encode(toConvert.trim());
byte[] charsAsBytes = bytes.array();
```

I get an array that starts with -2 and -1. Where do these values come from? Do they mean anything or can I skip these. The default charset is UTF-8.

Comment: Do you really want to use UTF-16?  There is a good chance UTF-8 will be smaller if not more widely used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bytes in Java are interpreted as signed two's complement, so -2 and -1 represent `0xFE` and `0xFF`. In the beginning of UTF-16 encoded text this is the [byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

Citing Wikipedia:

> In UTF-16, a BOM (`U+FEFF`) may be placed as the first character of a
>   file or character stream to indicate the endianness (byte order) of
>   all the 16-bit code units of the file or stream.